# Add HTML Attributes To Anchor Tags In `wp_list_categories()` Function

Tags: php, categories, html, accessibility

I'm using the `wp_list_categories()` function which generates an unordered list with list items and anchor tags for the categories. Is there any way to add HTML attributes to the `<a>` tags which hold the category links?

I'd like to add a `title` attribute which is the same as the category, and a `class` attribute, but looking at the docs, in the list of associative array properties I can't see how to do this?

The code I'm using is:

```
<?php
    echo '<ul class="cat-sidebar-list">';
        $args_list = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'news_categories',
        'show_count' => false,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'title_li' => '',
        );   
        echo wp_list_categories($args_list);
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: wp_list_categories() doesn't have an option to modify attributes for category 
link. Code screenshot: https://monosnap.com/file/zGKB1D9HxeavjtALrg56MQdvKTulkC

You can either use the filter `wp_list_categories` to modify the output using regex, or you can write a custom function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default walker used by `wp_list_categories()` ([`Walker_Category`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_category/)) has a hook (a filter hook) named [`category_list_link_attributes`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/category_list_link_attributes/) which you can use to add custom `title` and `class` (as well as other attributes like `data-xxx`) to the *anchor*/`a` tag (`<a>`) in the HTML list generated via `wp_list_categories()`.

So for example, you can do something like:

```php
add_filter( 'category_list_link_attributes', 'my_category_list_link_attributes', 10, 2 );
function my_category_list_link_attributes( $atts, $category ) {
    // Set the title to the category description if it's available. Else, use the name.
    $atts['title'] = $category->description ? $category->description : $category->name;

    // Set a custom class.
    $atts['class'] = 'custom-class category-' . $category->slug;
//  $atts['class'] .= ' custom-class';                 // or append a new class
//  $atts['class'] = 'custom-class ' . $atts['class']; // or maybe prepend it

    return $atts;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ever so much Sally!

Answer (score 1):

#### Custom Walker

The function [wp_list_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/) accepts a (custom) walker. That gives you the possibility to add a custom function that adds class and title attribute to the output. The function has no filter hook so that you have not the option to change the default output of the function.

an example to use a custom walker at the function.

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'id',
    'show_count' => 0,
    'walker' => new My_Custom_Walker_Category(),
);
wp_list_categories($args);
```

The custom walker is an extension of the default, like ([Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_category/))

```
class My_Custom_Walker_Category extends Walker_Category {
    function start_el( &$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
    }
}
```

#### Only CSS classes

A simple solution is possible only for the CSS classes. The default walker has a filter hook to change, enhance the CSS classes - [category_css_class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/category_css_class/). The filter has all parameters documented.

```
        /**
         * Filters the list of CSS classes to include with each category in the list.
         *
         * @since 4.2.0
         *
         * @see wp_list_categories()
         *
         * @param array  $css_classes An array of CSS classes to be applied to each list item.
         * @param object $category    Category data object.
         * @param int    $depth       Depth of page, used for padding.
         * @param array  $args        An array of wp_list_categories() arguments.
         */
        $css_classes = implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'category_css_class', $css_classes, $category, $depth, $args ) );
```

#### The Walker

More hooks and hints about the Walker class will you find inside [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/files/wp-includes/class-walker-category.php/). The Walker has [three hooks](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/files/wp-includes/class-walker-category.php/?post_type%5B%5D=wp-parser-hook).

- `category_description`
- `category_css_class`
- `category_list_link_attributes`

Answer (score 0):

If you only wanted to output the category name as the title attribute, you could do that simply by entering the category name in the Category Description field because the default output is to use that field as the title attribute UNLESS you set that flag in $args to 0 (false - see use_desc_for_title the default is 1, true).

But a simpler way to do what you want is to output the results of wp_list_categories() instead of echoing (set 'echo' to 0 instead of the default 1) and then you can set your HTML however you like for $output.

So an example (similar to that found in the Codex) would be (remember you can remove/ignore any for which the default is what you want):

```
wp_list_categories( $args = '' ) {
$defaults = array(
    'child_of'            => 0,
    'current_category'    => 0,
    'depth'               => 0,
    'echo'                => 0,
    'exclude'             => '',
    'exclude_tree'        => '',
    'feed'                => '',
    'feed_image'          => '',
    'feed_type'           => '',
    'hide_empty'          => 1,
    'hide_title_if_empty' => false,
    'hierarchical'        => true,
    'order'               => 'ASC',
    'orderby'             => 'name',
    'separator'           => '<br />',
    'show_count'          => 0,
    'show_option_all'     => '',
    'show_option_none'    => __( 'No categories' ),
    'style'               => 'list',
    'taxonomy'            => 'category',
    'title_li'            => __( 'Categories' ),
    'use_desc_for_title'  => 1,
)};

$parsed_args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

$categories = get_categories( $parsed_args );
 if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
 
 echo '<ul>';
   foreach ($categories as $category) {
   echo '<li class="' . esc_attr( $parsed_args['class'] ) . '">' . $parsed_args['title_li'];
   }

   echo '</ul>';
  }
```

Keep in mind that while you can add any additional style classes you want this way, the default is to output a class for each category ID, so you already have some granular style options built in.  And as mentioned the default output for the title attribute is the Category Description so assuming you're not already using that field for an actual description, just putting the Category name there will do what you want without additional code.

EDITED: Chewy, you can remove any lines in the $args (defaults) that are set as you already want them to be according to their defaults - you only need to list them if you are changing from what is the default per the Codex.  In the list above, 'echo' is set to 0 meaning that it will return the results to you, not list them, which is why just below that in the foreach statement you have to open the UL, then loop through the results to create the LI for each one.

THE ONLY reason I can see to do this is so you can *add* the styles you said in your OP that you want to add.....if you can live with the unique styles WP adds already (the category ID is added as a class to each category listed), then you don't need to do any of this, all you need to do is call wp_list_categories() in your template where you want them, and put your preferred Title Attribute in the category's Description field.

Comment: Hi @Trisha that code is throwing an error - I think it's an error in the `foreach` part of it, but I can't seem to see where.

Comment: My apologies Chewy, I just threw that together as an example, I didn't take the time to test it. What error do you get?

Comment: The syntax highlighter is highlighting the first line of the `foreach` method and is showing the following message is the VSCode debugger `"message": "syntax error, unexpected '$categories' (T_VARIABLE), expecting '('",`

Comment: Gah! My bad.... that line should be written with the parenthesis, like this: 
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {

Comment: It's now showing more errors on the line inside the `foreach`. Also is this code meant to go in my functions.php file or template file (where my current code is)? I get more errors showing in the template file than when in functions.php but all the errors show on the line inside the `foreach` function. Sample image for errors when in functions.php https://snipboard.io/qXFD17.jpg

Comment: Hi Chewy, it does not go in your functions file, it goes in your template where you want to display your list of categories. That line ("$output. = ) is taken from the example shown in the WP Codex for the wp_list_categories function.....it can also be written without the space, like $output.= but that space shouldn't matter. 

I'm going to edit my original answer to clarify that section. Using 'echo' can sometimes have odd results, but it's worth trying in this case.

Comment: I've amended all of the code errors (remove the `$` before echo, added the missing parenthesis on the foreach and added a missing curly bracket on the initial 'defaults' array. I also changed the 'taxonomy' to `news_categories` in my version. The code now executes but doesn't work. It might be worth you setting up an actual test environment if you are going to add any more answers because I don't think it's going to work otherwise.

Comment: Let's revisit your goals, which you've stated is to a) add a title attribute and b) add some styles. The title attribute needs no coding - just put the Category Title into the Description field for each category. Regarding styles, the default is to output a unique style for each category (category-ID where ID is the category's actual ID). So as I previously stated, you can accomplish both goals without any coding.  What else do you need to accomplish? My initial answer was to show you examples from the Codex but as stated aren't necessary unless you need to add MORE styles. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm confused. I added the `'use_desc_for_title'  => 1` line to the bottom of my $args list and nothing happens? You said '`you could do that simply by entering the category name in the Category Description field` ....where is the Category Description Field? I'm not bothering adding a 'class' attribute now, it's only the title attribute that I need.

Comment: Now that I only want the `title` attribute it may be worth you doing a specific answer i.e. only adding what is specifically needed to my $args list to do this and the necessary additional code if needed. If you do that I can then edit the wording of the question and if it works give you the bounty points.

Comment: Note that I said you only need to list $args when you want something different than the defaults. In the case of the title attribute, "use_desc_for_title" defaults to 1 (true), meaning the category's description WILL be used as the title attribute. You don't need ANY of those $args unless you want to change them. You set the category's description in the same place where you add/edit your Categories (which is a sub-menu of Posts).  There are 4 fields - Name, Slug, Parent Category, and Description.  To use the Category's name as the title attribute, just put it into the Description field.  :-)

Comment: Don't worry I got a simple answer which I marked as correct.